pytube library could not find match for ^\w+\W
i recently tried to download a youtube video using pytube library as below :
from pytube import YouTube

def download_video(url, resolution):
    try:
        yt = YouTube(url)
        streams = yt.streams.filter(res=f'{resolution}p', progressive=True).first()
        if streams:
            print(f"Downloading {yt.title} in {resolution}p resolution...")
            streams.download()
            print("Download completed successfully!")
        else:
            print(f"No {resolution}p resolution available for this video.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = input("Enter the YouTube video link: ")
    resolution = input("Enter the desired resolution (e.g., 144, 240, 360, 480, 720, 1080): ")
    download_video(url, resolution)

but when i specify the resolution it brings me back this error :
An error occurred: __init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W

i search the internet for any solution and find this :

C:\Users#####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py
replace the line 30, which is:
var_regex = re.compile(r"^\w+\W")
with this line :
var_regex = re.compile(r"^$\w+\W")

but unfortunately it doesn't work for me either.
it is very strange because my code worked fine yesterday but now it doesn't work anymore.
i am using google colab
and my location is germany.

Try using this instead:
var_regex = re.compile(r"^\$*\w+\W")

It worked on my end.
Found the answer here

Your answer could be improved if you [edit] to have the essential information in the answer and the link as a reference.

There's a new commit in the official repo that fixes it. But you can solve it easily by changing a simple line in the cipher.py file by:
ALL CREDITS TO @abhiram-ar. He made the following fix:

Import pytube's class Cipher into your code
Write your own class by just copy-pasting Cipher and replacing one line of code
Rewrite Cipher with your custom class

from pytube import cipher

class CustomCipher:
    def __init__(self, js: str):
        self.transform_plan: List[str] = get_transform_plan(js)
        # var_regex = re.compile(r"^\w+\W")
        var_regex = re.compile(r"^[\w\$_]+\W")
        # other class code...

cipher.Cipher = CustomCipher

